# How to properly make checking what letter contains in variable char?

Tags: c++

The code above that, I think, not neccesary here, but just in case :

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath> 
using namespace std; 

struct ANKETA1
{
    int age;
    char gender;
    string education;
};

struct ANKETA2
{
    char address[55];
    int numberOfAdultsInFamily;
};

struct ANKETA
{
    ANKETA1 firstAnketa;
    ANKETA2 secondAnketa;
};

int main(){

    int N;
    cout<<"Number of ankets: ";
    cin>>N;
    cout<<endl;

    ANKETA ankets[N];

}
```

The code I have written :

```
for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
cout<<"Anketa #"<<i+1<<endl;

 do{
    cout<<"Enter your gender ( M - Male, F - Female ) : ";
    cin>>ankets[i].firstAnketa.gender;

    if(ankets[i].firstAnketa.gender != 'F' || ankets[i].firstAnketa.gender != 'M'){

            cout<<"Enter M or F accordingly to your gender"<<endl;}}

 while(ankets[i].firstAnketa.gender !='M' && ankets[i].firstAnketa.gender != 'F'); 
...
```

I want the program to work like this :

If user enters 'F' or 'M', everything should be OK and program goes below.
But if user enters another letter, program should ask him to enter again.

But this program

If I enter 'M' or 'F' , the program still prints :

"Enter M or F accordingly to your gender"

and only after this message goes below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OR `||` should be an AND `&&`.

```
if(ankets[i].firstAnketa.gender != 'F' || ankets[i].firstAnketa.gender != 'M')
```

should be

```
if(ankets[i].firstAnketa.gender != 'F' && ankets[i].firstAnketa.gender != 'M')
```

The `if` check in your `while` loop will always be `true` the way you have it written.